# when do we consider the moles in bomb calorimeter?

Tags: thermodynamics

When dealing with different problems in thermodynamics
I noticed that some of the problem consider the number of moles in calculating the heat absorbed or released, whereas some don't and they deal with the heat,capacity,difference in temperature WITHOUT considering the number of moles

example1:       1 gram of a sample burns in .....
they divide the grams over the molar mass to get the moles, then multiply by the enthalpy and solve for the needed.

example2:       1 gram of a sample burns in ....
they get one one of (q,C,delta H) directly without considering the number of moles.

what's the difference?

Comment: It depends on what you are measuring. Sometimes for instance you'll use "molar" enthalpy so you'll normalized for a mole. Sometimes you'll just use enthalpy then you don't need to normalize.